# JSon format to invoke REST service

Tags: json, wcf, rest

I have a wcf REST Service which is calling a method that updates something in the database. The method takes a parameter.

lets say my is `void MarkMobileAppApplicationAsCancelled(string applicationId);`

Now I am trying to invoke that service using one app from chrome app store called CREST. but I  dont know how to invoke that method in Json format.

Any help??

I have some thing like

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/MarkMobileAppApplicationAsConfirmed/")]
        void MarkMobileAppApplicationAsConfirmed(string applicationId);
```

what i am trying is initialize this method which will update my database by setting the application's application_confirmed = true,

I wrote the following in the Request Builder

```
https://local.blaSys.com/MobileAppWCF.svc/MarkMobileAppApplicationAsCancelled/
```

and the following in the header

```
content-type:application/json
```

Now, what would i write in the Request Entity??

Comment: Please clearify your definition of REST: Do you simply mean a webservice that communicates using json and have resource specific urls? If you provide your service interface it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: i am new in wcf. Please see the updates in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you would not want to write anything in the request, but rather get the `applicationID` from the url.

You can obtain this by using a slight modification

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/MarkMobileAppApplicationAsConfirmed/{applicationID}")]
    void MarkMobileAppApplicationAsConfirmed(string applicationId);
```

Now you can simply make a standard http request (using curl/fiddler for testing and WebClient/WebRequest) in the proxy against the endpoint

https://local.blaSys.com/MobileAppWCF.svc/MarkMobileAppApplicationAsCancelled/someApplicationId

Remember that the method given to the request must be `POST` as indicated in the `WebInvoke` attribute. (I guess a `PUT` would be more idiomatically correct since you must be updating a method, but that is another discussion.)

Hope this helps!